# Jquery - auto generating serial number for rows delete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a dynamic table like below and its rows were generating with serial number.

My problem is when am deleting from bottom it is giving the same continuation number,but when am deleting from the top say 1 or 2, its the next row is not giving right serial number.

```
        // function remove
        function removeItem(param){
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('inventory_id',param);
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo 'deleteItem.php'; ?>",
                dataType:'json',
                data:form_data,
                cache:false,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                type:'post',
                success:function(res_data){
                    if (res_data.status == 1) {
                        var row = "#row"+param
                        $(row).hide();
                        document.getElementById('roll_no').value=roll--;

                        //roll--;

                    }
                    console.log(res_data);
                },
            });
            }

        $(function(){
            $('#addItem').click(function(){
                var form_data = new FormData();
                form_data.append('store_code',$('#itemCode').val());
                form_data.append('store_desc',$('#storeCode').val());
                form_data.append('qty',$('#itemQty').val());
                form_data.append('epo',$('#epo').val());
                $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo 'addItem.php'; ?>",
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:form_data,
                    cache:false,
                    contentType:false,
                    processData:false,
                    type:'post',
                    success:function(res_data){
                        roll=parseInt(document.getElementById('roll_no').value);
                        var row = "<tr id='row"+res_data.id+"'><td class='text_normalarial'><lable id="+res_data+"roll class=jibi007>"+roll+"</label></td><td class='text_normalarial'>"+res_data.item_id+"</td><td class='text_normalarial'>"+res_data.store_id+"</td><td class='text_normalarial'>"+res_data.qty+"</td><td><button style='width:20px;height:20px;border:none;background:url(images/close_new.png)' class='round' onclick='removeItem("+res_data.id+")'></button></td></tr>"
                        document.getElementById('roll_no').value=roll+1;
                        $('#inventory').append(row);

                        console.log(res_data);
                    },
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: What does the console show any errors?

Comment: Thank You for writing the reply. It doesnt give any error. The problem what am facing is when am deleting a dynamically generated row  from top let say SL NO 1 or SL NO 2 from 5 rows, then its not re ordering the serial number @Mister Positive

Comment: https://snag.gy/0T72y5.jpg for screenshot @SOReadyToHelp